# multiple apps on apache server

Tags: php, apache, web, server

I am developing a PHP web application and did deploy it on Apache web Server port 80, However I need to deploy the old version of the application again for testing purpose. I would like to deploy the old version on the same web server with minimal configuration to it.
the first app already deployed under /var/www/html
I would like to deploy the old version under /var/www/old on port 81 for example

how this can be done ? do I need to make changes to Apache configuration or create new Virtual Hosts ?

Regards,

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new Virtual Host with the same domain but on port 81 and point it to `/var/www/old`

Comment: cool. can you tell me where to make these changes ? I am running on ubuntu box. I am not fimiliar with administration the Apache server.

Comment: If you install [Webmin](https://webmin.com/) - you will be able to create the Virtual Host through a friendly UI - the documentation is [here](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Apache_Webserver)

Comment: The Apache documentation and numerous blogs, examples, previous questions etc discuss setting up virtual hosts. Have you done any research since that suggestion was given to you? We probably don't need to repeat any such information unless you try it and get stuck with something specific (in which case you should show your attempt and explain the problem)

Comment: Chill ADyson, not all people are fimiliar with administration Apache. I did look around but need pointers to how to do it.   Thanks IVO GELOV I will look into Webmin, it's new to me.

Comment: I'm perfectly chilled. Obviously not everyone is familiar, but that is what research is for. We're happy to give you pointers but first you need to explain what pointers you would need, specifically. Where are you stuck, what have you tried so far based on your research?